# remove tag from joomla using jQuery

Tags: jquery, joomla

i am trying to remove some specific tags from my joomla 2.5 web site using javascript.
So i have created my custom.js placed it in the root directory and included in the template index file and it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/myjs.js"></script>
```

Then the jquery code inside the .js is:

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.product-description>h1').hide();
});
```

even though in the terminal works fine and hides the specific h1 when i run it through my js file it doesn't.
The console is clear.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you also have to add jquery to your page as well please add this

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
```

in head.php file in your joomla installation or include it in index file

Comment: sorry,it is a joomla 2.5 installation. I cant find any head.php .

Comment: i added the script <script type="text/javascript"  src="myjs.js"> in the index.php and it broke the site.

Comment: http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla-Developer-FAQs/How-to-add-javascript-to-Joomla-articles-plugins-modules-or-components.php this will help you